# WebTemplate for 'saved sites a template'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site, web-template, flow, ms-flow

I am using MS Flow to POST a HTTP request to SharePoint to create a Sub site when an item has be entered into a list.

I want to create this sub site using a site template I have saved.

[image]

I am trying to figure out the ID for my Sharepoint Site Template but I am not sure where this to find it?
I have checked out this site but not able to find anything here:

[SharePoint templates and their Ids](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2010/10/21/sharepoint-templates-and-their-ids/)

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to find the template ID for this site template or do you need it in the flow dynamically?

Comment: Hi Ganesh,

I'm trying to create a subsite using a custom template that I have created.
I have tried to put in the TemplateID but this hasn't worked.
https://imgur.com/a/ctYGViS

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, please post the error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NBSsJ5x
https://imgur.com/a/1lOUKIH
2 screenshots showing the template IT and my MS flow.
I also found this that said to use this ""WebTemplate": "{7AEDBA9E-5CCE-4281-85D3-E311DA3A6766}#mytemplate", "

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/65805d54-4ebe-4bf4-87b8-aebc01c03afd/create-document-library-from-custom-template-via-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Managed to get this working - I forgot the brackets around the Template ID.
https://imgur.com/a/yy2Ex9B

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Great. Enjoy SharePointing :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to find out the TemplateId for custom template:

1. **Using User Interface**:

Go to the site creation page where you selects the custom site template to create new site. Locate the site template you want to use and Press F12 or Right click > Inspect Element.

[image]

2. **Using Programming**:

The following code will return WebTemplateId using its site template name:

```
function CreateSubsiteByTemplateName(templateTitle) {  
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    var web = context.get_web();  
    context.load(web);  
    var webTemplates = web.getAvailableWebTemplates(1033, false);  
    context.load(webTemplates);  
    context.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {  
        var enumerator = webTemplates.getEnumerator();  
        var templateId = "STS#0";  
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
            var webTemplate = enumerator.get_current();  
            var webTitle = webTemplate.get_title();  
            if (webTitle == templateTitle) {  
                templateId = webTemplate.get_name();  
                break;  
            }  
        }  
        return templateId;  
    }, function(sender, args) {  
        alert(args.get_message())  
    });  
}
```

**References**:

1. [How To Find Custom Template ID Using Template Name In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-find-custom-template-id-using-template-name-in-sharepoint).
2. [Microsoft Flow – Create a new sub site using Microsoft Flow!](https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/05/02/microsoft-flow-create-a-new-sub-site-using-microsoft-flow/amp/).
3. [Create SharePoint site by custom template and grant permissions in Microsoft Flow](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-site-by-custom-template-and-grant-permissions.html).